# Most efficient method to use R to import data stored on Amazon S3 bucket to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, amazon-s3

I have a large number of large CSV files (ranging from 1.2 - 1.5 GB each) stored on an Amazon S3 bucket. I'd like to import/load these files into a Microsoft SQL Server database.

I've been trying to use the aws.s3 package in R to handle this, but I'm looking for guidance on how to do this most efficiently in terms of loading data into memory/saving to physical drive.

I'm also open to other recommendations for how to handle this outside of R. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid loading the CSVs into R.  Every SQL implementation has a way to bulk import entries in csv/text tables.

I found this for SQL server:

```
BULK INSERT Sales.Orders
FROM '\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\data\orders.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

So a workflow in R would look like this:

1) loop over files, call `aws ls` to list all the files

2) `aws cp` file to disk

3) Call system command to bulk insert CSV to table (You could use `Rsqlite` or other R packages to help automate SQL commands. )

4) Delete csv file

Comment: Thanks - this is what I needed! I ended up using bcp.exe instead of BULK INSERT because my SQL Server database didn't allow the latter. Thanks much!